# Solr Update Issues

Tags: java, solr, solrj

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://{ip}/solr/{core}: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid^M
response from an upstream server.<br />^M
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/solr/cms/update">POST&nbsp;/solr/cms/update</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
```

Used solr version -> 6.5.0  Type -> master/Slave config
The rate of update query on master solr is 6 request per min only .
Solr also slows down and search becomes really slow .
I don't understand where to look for an issue .
I have tried to check various parameters in update request , if I do softcommit as true and commit as false then updates do not reflect .
Any suggestion to debug it will be highly appreciated

Error in solr.log ->

```
2020-10-07 05:43:50.639 WARN  (qtp142261320-27831) [   x:cms] o.a.s.c.SolrCore slow: [cms]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={waitSearcher=true&commit=true&softCommit=false&wt=javabin&version=2} status=0 QTime=44327
2020-10-07 05:43:50.640 WARN  (qtp142261320-27837) [   x:cms] o.a.s.u.DefaultSolrCoreState WARNING - Dangerous interrupt
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.tryLock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:871)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.lock(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:167)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:112)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:618)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:93)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1895)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1872)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerUtils.handleCommit(RequestHandlerUtils.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:72)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2440)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:347)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
```

Comment: PLEASE DON'T YELL AT US

Comment: Ohh .. not yelling . Don't mind .

Comment: What is the underlying file system for the server? Seeing as it's having trouble acquiring locks, you can try to adjust the lock type: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/indexconfig-in-solrconfig.html - the default uses the file system as its locking mechanism, so if the file system is flakey (for example if it's on nfs or through a VM mounted endpoint that doesn't behave properly) it might fail.